# Facebook returning null

Tags: android, facebook

```
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     Process: com.example.ricardo.tcc2, PID: 31818
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity      {com.example.ricardo.tcc2/com.example.ricardo.tcc2.Facebook}:     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method     'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object reference
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4008)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4039)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1682)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object reference
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ricardo.tcc2.BlankFragment.onResume(BlankFragment.java:168)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2052)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:187)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:462)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:451)
 03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6639)
 03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4039) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1682) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
03-03 17:36:46.791 31818-31818/com.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

This is my Facebook class.

```
public class Facebook extends FragmentActivity {

private BlankFragment mainFragment;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;


public String name;
public String id;
public String imageUrl;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);



    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    printHashkey();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new BlankFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (BlankFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }



}


public void printHashkey(){
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "name",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



public void goToAttract(View v)
{
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    getProfile(profile);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("Nome", name);
    b.putString("ID", id);
    intent.putExtras(b);

    setResult(1, intent);
    finish();
}



public void getProfile(Profile profile){
    if(profile != null){
        id = profile.getId().toString();
        name = profile.getName().toString();

    }
}


}
```

This is my Fragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {



private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private TextView textView;
private ImageView imv;

private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
private Button btnVoltar;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        displayMessage(profile);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

public BlankFragment() {

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

        }
    };

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            displayMessage(newProfile);
        }
    };

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btnVoltar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);


    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);



}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}

private void displayMessage(Profile profile){

    TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ProfilePictureView profileImage = (ProfilePictureView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    profileImage.setProfileId(profile.getId());

    if(profile != null){
        textView.setText(profile.getName());
        profileImage.setProfileId(profile.getId());

    }

}



@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    ProfilePictureView profileImage = (ProfilePictureView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    profileImage.setProfileId(profile.getId());
    displayMessage(profile);


}







}
```

On my MainActivity I have a side menu that links to the facebook class.
It was working fine. Now it started to show this error. I don't get why.

Any help pls?

Comment: [checkmark]: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/faceerro-png--2    Always get this error. Was looking for an answer here for hours but still cant get why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try reading your errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object reference
```

This means that the Profile object you are trying to use is null. Figure out why it is null. Don't assume just because it worked before, this isn't an issue. Perhaps it's an issue you didn't actually encounter because of certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works. Still testing. 
If profile is null it shows the login Button.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    if (profile != null) {
        ProfilePictureView profileImage = (ProfilePictureView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        profileImage.setProfileId(profile.getId());
        displayMessage(profile);
    }
}
```